# How To Build Collapsible Lightning component of 3 level

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, sfdc-styleguide

**How To Build Collapsible Lightning component of 3 level**

- Level3
  +Level2
   Level1

level2 dependent on level3 and level1 dependent on level2

for ex:Bundle product--> Option Product --->Features

one bundle product could have multiple options and one option product could have multiple features.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [lightning:tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree) or [lightning:treeGrid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid) to build such a table. Example code is included in the documentation. Also, you can take a look at my very old [tree demo](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/32bd056260cf4850ba15bc5641b6c42f) if you're interested in how the underlying mechanics work. The example from lightning:treeGrid looks like this:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:attribute name="gridColumns" type="List" access="PRIVATE" />
    <aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object" access="PRIVATE" />
    <aura:attribute name="gridExpandedRows" type="List" access="PRIVATE" />


    <div>
        <lightning:treeGrid
            columns="{! v.gridColumns }"
            data="{! v.gridData }"
            expandedRows="{! v.gridExpandedRows }"
            keyField="name"
        />
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

---

```
({ // eslint-disable-line
    init: function (cmp) {
        var columns = [
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'accountName',
                label: 'Account Name',
                initialWidth: 300
            },
            {
                type: 'number',
                fieldName: 'employees',
                label: 'Employees'
            },
            {
                type: 'phone',
                fieldName: 'phone',
                label: 'Phone Number'
            },
            {
                type: 'url',
                fieldName: 'accountOwner',
                label: 'Account Owner',
                typeAttributes: {
                    label: { fieldName: 'accountOwnerName' }
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'billingCity',
                label: 'Billing City'
            }
        ];

        cmp.set('v.gridColumns', columns);

        // data
        var nestedData = [
            {
                "name": "123555",
                "accountName": "Rewis Inc",
                "employees": 3100,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                "billingCity": "Phoeniz, AZ"
            },

            {
                "name": "123556",
                "accountName": "Acme Corporation",
                "employees": 10000,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123556-A",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (Bay Area)",
                        "employees": 3000,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                        "_children": [
                            {
                                "name": "123556-A-A",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (Oakland)",
                                "employees": 745,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                                "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "123556-A-B",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (San Francisco)",
                                "employees": 578,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                                "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA"
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "123556-B",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (East)",
                        "employees": 430,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA",
                        "_children": [
                            {
                                "name": "123556-B-A",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (NY)",
                                "employees": 1210,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                                "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "123556-B-B",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (VA)",
                                "employees": 410,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                                "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                                "_children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "123556-B-B-A",
                                        "accountName": "Allied Technologies",
                                        "employees": 390,
                                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                                        "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                                        "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA",
                                        "_children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "123556-B-B-A-A",
                                                "accountName": "Allied Technologies (UV)",
                                                "employees": 270,
                                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                                                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                                                "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "name": "123557",
                "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises",
                "employees": 6000,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123557-A",
                        "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises (UCA)",
                        "employees": 2540,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "name": "123558",
                "accountName": "Tech Labs",
                "employees": 1856,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123558-A",
                        "accountName": "Opportunity Resources Inc",
                        "employees": 1934,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        cmp.set('v.gridData', nestedData);


        var expandedRows = ["123556", "123556-A", "123556-B", "123556-B-B", "123557"];

        cmp.set('v.gridExpandedRows', expandedRows);
    }
}); // eslint-disable-line
```

Comment: could you pls share  apex code to bring data from objects in this format.

Comment: @NikhilBajaj You just need to write a wrapper class, or you could retrieve the data in pieces and reconstruct it on the client. This is going to take quite a bit of code, but it should all be pretty basic. Why don't you give it a try first, and ask a new question if you get stuck.